# SAP CPI HTTP Post how to pass token

Tags: http, web-services, token, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cpi

I need to send a POST in CPI to a s4hana service, and in order to pass it directly in JSON, not in xml, I want to use the simple HTTP adapter.

How can I get the token with a GET and use it with a POST afterwards?

Comment: Hello, sorry and thank you for answering, indeed it solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the GET, parse the XML and save the token as a variable in message header.
Use the message header variable in your POST via filling the JSON with ${header.yourVariableName}

see this: 
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/18/sap-cpi-clearing-the-headers-reset-header/ 
http://blog.whint.de/runtime-variables-cpi/